# ANSYS GPU Acceleration Problem "Partial Pivoting"

Tags: ansys-workbench

When i try to use GPU in ANSYS 2022 R2 the warning appears as "gpu accelerator capability is not supported when the partial pivoting logic is activated. the GPU accelerator capability is disabled"

How should i close partial pivoting ?

Comment: Is this on a particular PC?

Comment: What do you mean by particular PC ? It is a PC not a workstation, yes. The GPU is supported

Comment: Dell, HP, Alienware etc Have you tested other architectures? Like Mac, or Unix?

Comment: HP Workstation, Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried searching for the answer? [Here](https://forum.ansys.com/forums/topic/gpu-acceleration-and-partial-pivoting/) is the first result for googling "ansys partial pivoting logic" from which it seems you cannot directly control this, but it is activated only under specific circumstances.

Comment: Before asking, yes I have checked the link that you posted. It says mixed u-P elements causes partial pivoting. I was asking for is there any option to close this feature. I think only solution is to force not to use element with mixed u-P formulation. I am adding a [link](https://www.mm.bme.hu/~gyebro/files/ans_help_v182/ans_thry/thy_geo5.html) for those who needed later. You can find the formulation in 3.6.3.